# Customized FLV Player Skin for web page

Tags: javascript, actionscript, dreamweaver, flash

Can any one suggest a way or tutorial link to customize my FLV player skin.? I tried to use the pre built flv skins from adobe flash.. But as i'm generating the flv source dynamically in my website i am unable to pass the source name in the HTML page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your variables in this way

```
 <param name="FlashVars" value="variable1=value" />
```

And in flash receive it as

```
myVariable = root.loaderInfo.parameters.variable1
```